# Jasmine Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "hooks is undefined"

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, hook

All of my individual Protractor tests in a given Jasmine spec have passed, but the spec still fails with this message:

```
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "hooks is undefined"
```

I haven't been able to find any information on the meaning of "hooks is undefined".

Using
protractor@5.1.2
firefox 57.0.3

There is no stack trace; the full text of the error is as follows:

```
An error was thrown in an afterAll
AfterAll Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "hooks is undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error can be thrown when protractor tries to interact with a page during the beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, or afterEach hook, before angular has loaded on that page.  It can be caused for essentially the same reason as "cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined".

A possible solution is to put this in the line above any protractor activity in the hook:

```
browser.sleep(2000);
```

And/Or increase the length of an existing sleep in your before/after hook, so that the page has time for angular to load first, before invoking protractor.

Comment: I am a serious believer that `browser.sleep()` is never a good solution to anything :) Could you please edit your question and add some information about what protractor version you are using, your protractor config and the complete traceback of the error? I'd like to investigate it a little bit further. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, there might be a way to dynamically wait for Angular to be ready on the page, but ExpectedConditions and waitForAngular don't work until Angular has loaded and I haven't found any other way to wait for Angular to load other than browser.sleep().

Comment: I personally think that the test execution performance time loss caused by hard-coded sleeps is negligible when compared to the extra engineering effort involved in always avoiding them.  If it were just a lot of work to find a reliable way to avoid them, that would be one thing -- but in my experience, Selenium suites that are built to avoid sleep also tend to throw false failures as a result -- especially in Angular!  If a false failure that could have been avoided with sleep delays the team's ability to merge good code, even once or twice... was it worth the half-second we saved?

Comment: You have a point there, but let's not go this way, we are going to flood the comments with going back and forth on an "support" theme for this thread :) I'm still curious what is exactly happening in this case - never needed to give that delay for Angular to kick in. Please provide the above-mentioned details if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Details provided.  It's interesting that you haven't needed to wait for angular to kick in - I need to sleep at at least 500ms regularly before it will accept a browser.waitForAngular() or any other protractor interaction after a new page loads from a direct get to the URL.  Browsing to links within an angular app does not seem to require the sleep.

Comment: Could you please also post your protractor config? Especially the `onPrepare()` part. Also, what Angular version are you dealing with?
 Thanks.